# SpringBoot: set application property back to default

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to set an application property back to its default value?

I am working on a SpringBootProject with different profiles, setting application properties.

In application.yml the logging format f.e. ist PLAIN

```
mycompany:
  logging:
    format: PLAIN
```

Then the profile for selenium-tests on the integration server application-selenium.yml sets it to JSON

```
mycompany:
  logging:
    format: JSON
```

To work on the profile for selenium-tests locally I set it back to PLAIN in application-dev.yml

```
mycompany:
  logging:
    format: PLAIN
```

Would there be a way to reset the property to its default value in application-dev.yml?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do - you can rollback you local changes with git (`git restore application-dev.yml`) Would be simpler to just create another properties file `application-selenium-dev.yml` if you need to do this regularly

Comment: Are you sure it is taking dev profile on tests? How are you choosing profiles?
For tests you should create your application-test.yml or specfy new configuration properties on tests.

Comment: tanks for your response.

Yes the above dev profile is working, but I wanted to know, if there is a way not to write 'PLAIN', but somehow to set ist back to default. like '' or null or #DEFAULT, ...